# Inter Container Communication from outside the Host using public ip

Tags: docker, docker-network

==>I have multiple containers running on the cloud and intercommunication among containers works fine while I am logged into the host.

==>But when I try to access the application using an elastic ip or public ip from outside the host.

Container `A(172.17.0.2)` tries to reach container `B(172.17.0.3)` at `172.17.0.3/8080`. Whereas I want container A to reach container B using the `public-ip:8080` because `172.17.0.3/8080` address can't be accessed from outside the host.

Comment: How do you tell A, the address of B?

Comment: I don't have to do any configuration for that  if you inspect my default bridge network. you can see the two containers running inside the host and their ip's. Also when you run your container, you can attach it to another. I have also exposed the ports of these containers.